# What does degree mean here? Question about universal coefficient theorem and $KK$ theory.

Tags: homological-algebra, c-star-algebras, topological-k-theory

Universal Coefficient Theorem 1.17. Let $A\in\mathcal N$. Then there is a short exact sequence

$$
0\to \text{Ext}(K_*(A),K_*(B))\stackrel{\delta}\to KK_*(A,B)\stackrel{\gamma}\to \text{Hom}(K_*(A),K_*(B))\to 0$$

The map $\gamma$ has degree $0$ and the map $\delta$ has degree $1$.

This is a theorem from *THE KUNNETH THEOREM AND THE UNIVERSAL
COEFFICIENT THEOREM FOR KASPAROV’S
GENERALIZED K-FUNCTOR,
JONATHAN ROSENBERG AND CLAUDE SCHOCHET*

I can't figure out whether $\delta$ is a $\text{Ext}(K_{i+1}(A),K_{i+1}(B))\to KK_i(A,B)$ map or a $\text{Ext}(K_{i}(A),K_{i}(B))\oplus \text{Ext}(K_{i+1}(A),K_{i+1}(B))\to KK_i(A,B)$ map or a  $\text{Ext}(K_{i}(A),K_{i+1}(B))\oplus \text{Ext}(K_{i+1}(A),K_{i}(B))\to KK_i(A,B)$ map.

It seems the paper is proving the first one but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what degree means exactly, but I think I have figured out what map it is here.

It is
$$
0\to \oplus_j \text{Ext}(K_j(A),K_{i+j-1}(B))\stackrel{\delta}\to KK_i(A,B)\stackrel{\gamma}\to \oplus_j \text{Hom}(K_j(A),K_{j+i}(B))\to 0
$$